# How to program this specific layout in my iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout

I would like to have a layout similar as this one and also to be able to pinch to zoom.
Do you have a great idea ?

[layout exemple](http://www.tinypic.ca/images/9o2iinyg4892wk09v8u.jpg)

I investigating using an UIWebView or construct this with CoreText..

Thanks for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach is to make it with HTML and UIWebVIew. CoreText is also good but it will require much more code. I would try with HTML and if the performance is good then I would do it with it ;)